# File upload with PHP and mySQL doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql, model-view-controller, mysqli

I try to upload Photos and save the path in the mySQL Db

What do I need to do so I can save the files to the database?

Controller:

```
public function doAddPhoto(){
    $view = new View('addPhoto');
    if(isset($_POST['uploadBtn']))
    {

        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $folder="uploads/";
        move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);

        $photoModel = new PhotoModel();
        $photoModel->create($file, $file_type, $file_size);

    }

    $view->display();

}
```

Model:

```
public function create($file, $file_type, $file_size){
    $query = "INSERT INTO $this->tableName (file, type, size) VALUES         (?, ?, ?)";

    $statement = ConnectionHandler::getConnection()->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('ssi', $file, $file_type, $file_size);
    $success = $statement->execute();
    if (!$success) {
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
    }
}
```

It displays the following error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in /PhotoController.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: file in /PhotoController.php on line 7
Notice: Undefined index: file in /PhotoController.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined index: file in /PhotoController.php on line 9

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in    /PhotoModel.php on line 5
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="/photo/doAddPhoto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Select image to upload:
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="uploadBtn">
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you post the html aswell? It can't find the name of the input(s).

Comment: Looks like your `$_FILES['file']` variable doesn't exist. Could you show your form ?

Comment: Where is is_uploaded_file() method ?